# How to order dynamically created Divs using jQuery based on a custom attribute that is a TimeStamp?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
var div = $("<div id='3.5'>AA</div>");
div_id_after = Math.floor(parseFloat(div.get(0).id));

$('#'+div_id_after).after(div);


<div id='1'>a</div>
<div id='2'>b</div>
<div id='3'>c</div>
<div id='4'>d</div>
<div id='5'>e</div>
```

This will produce the divs in this order:

a
b
c
AA
d
e

Clearly, it is not proper to use a number as an ID for IE/netscape compatibility issues, but bear with me.

**If you have divs which are created with a custom attribute "order", where the value of this attribute is a TimeStamp:**

```
<div order='2011-05-13 15:57:09'>a</div>
<div order='2011-05-14 11:23:02'>b</div>
<div order='2011-05-19 10:12:11'>c</div>
<div order='2011-06-10 12:39:37'>d</div>
<div order='2011-06-12 13:47:17'>e</div>
```

And, as in the code above you have an element:

```
var div = $("<div object='2011-05-19 17:46:21'>AA</div>");
```

How would you order these items, like the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (assumes that there is a parent div wrapping all of your items, id'd 'container').

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sort_me').click(doOrder);
});

function orderSort(a,b)
{
   return ($(a).attr('order') > $(b).attr('order')) ? 1 : -1;
}

function doOrder()
{
   var orderable = [];
   $('div[order]').each(function(idx,el){
      orderable.push(el);
   });
   orderable.sort(orderSort);
   for (var i=0; i < orderable.length;i++)
   {
        // Somewhat slow way of doing this.  Should be fine until you
        // get above 200 entries or so.  There are other ways which may 
        // be faster, but I thought this was good for explanation.
        $('#container').append(orderable[i]);
   }
}
```

---

added:
Forgot to add my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/fUC2A/3/

Comment: I have tested both this solution and the one below on my server and this one seems to work better.

There are no problems with this function beyond 1000 entries, I did not test more values than this. Thank you very much for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

I believe thats a non-standard date format so you would need to parse that somehow... try something like this:

```
function resortDivs(){
        var divCon = $('#divContainer');
        var divArr = $('#divContainer').children('div').get();
        var div = $("<div order='2011-05-19 17:46:21'>AA</div>")[0]; 
        divArr.push(div);
        divArr.sort(function(a,b){
            var parse1 = customDate($(a).attr('order'));
            var parse2 = customDate($(b).attr('order'));
            return parse1 > parse2 ? 1 : -1; 
        });
        $.each(divArr, function(idx, itm) {divCon.append(itm);});
}
function customDate(date){
    var ymd = date.split(' ')[0];
    var hms = date.split(' ')[1];
    ymd = ymd.split('-');
    hms = hms.split(':');
    return  new Date(ymd[0],ymd[1],ymd[2],hms[0],hms[1],hms[2]);
}
```

It gets all the elements into an array, sorts the array using a custom sort using your order attribute and then re-appends them to the container.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTanV/) - seems to be working.

Comment: Date format is ISO 8601 extended (no timezone designator).  Doesn't get much more standard from a real-world usage perspective.  The nice thing is that it is inherently string-comparable... YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS on a 24-hour clock.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike Actually I believe you need a literal 'T' between the DD and HH as specified here at w3: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime if the T was in there then it would be supported by `Date.parse(string)` making the comparison easier. Also, I would be wary of letting it stay a string comparison in case that is not the actual data OP is using and a custom compare would be beneficial.

Comment: I don't really think it matters much.  The Wikipedia article for 8601 is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601   |  There's an important bit in the 3rd paragraph of 'Combined date and time representations', which describes the format used here.  But if you want to get into date conversion... I'd probably recommend using an external library like Date.js, because it is a very complex problem to handle the myriad of formats out there.